# Shockwave Stun Rifle?

Tags: weapons, science-fiction, near-future

I'm looking for a kind of non-lethal weapon that can deliver a shockwave or energy blow to stun and disable a moving target for my sci-fi story. It's set in the future, so I could use a concept weapon as base.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: title indicates ranged weapon question doesn't mention range, do you want a ranged weapon?  You want to disable a moving target is the target a creature, a vehicle or a human?

Comment: You've just described a taser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this already exists! The weapon manufacture dialed down the power to make it non-lethal, but you could easily 'adjust' for this!

> Police and military forces around the world may soon have a new
>   non-lethal weapon at their hands. Called the Thunder Generator, the
>   device is a cannon that fires shock waves that pass through people and
>   objects. Although the shock waves are harmless, they give people the
>   impression of standing in front of a firing squad, according to the
>   cannon's developers.
>
> Originally, the Thunder Generator was used by farmers in Israel to
>   scare away birds that might eat their crops. Recently, Israel’s
>   Ministry of Defense has approved a license for the Israeli technology
>   company ArmyTec to market military and paramilitary versions of the
>   Thunder Generator. The company hopes that the cannon, which was
>   originally developed by Israeli company PDT Agro, could have
>   applications in crowd control and border security.
>
> "Anyone within 30 to 50 meters from the cannon will feel like he's
>   standing in front of a firing squad," said Igor Fridman, president of
>   PDT Agro, who developed the system. "He'll feel and hear the blast,
>   but he won't be hurled to the ground. He'll be able to run away
>   unharmed … and that's the point of this application."

Read more at: http://phys.org/news/2010-01-cannon-fired-stun-people.html#jCp

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this! I saw that video yesterday, but wasn't sure if it could be adjusted for actually hurling someone to the ground. Another option is a PEP weapon, similar to the P.E.P.S gun from Deus Ex.

Answer (score 4):

two modern equivalents

Electric blast

Taser shoots two darts that each trail a wire back to the device when they hit the target an electric shock is delivered to disable them.

Sonic shockwave

Flash bang 
Grenade with pressure wave and bright flash blinds, disorients (ruptures eardrum and ruins balance), and deafens targets

Water shockwave

Water cannon (high pressure fire hose) used by riot police to deal with large crowds.

With all  non-lethal weapons the major problem is the minimum amount of force that a prepared opponent can take without being disabled is much higher than the maximum amount of force that an unprepared person can survive.  Body armor or a layer of aluminum foil will block a taser.  Good ear protection will render a flashbang useless.  If you try to ramp up the voltage or the power of the explosive to break through these defenses then it will be too high to survive unprotected.

Comment: You could have a taser with variable voltage. Your first shot could be at low voltage and if that doesn't work up the voltage.

Comment: Yes but it cuts your fire rate in half, and gives a prepared target time to knock the wires / darts off.  Also decent body armor or a sweater soaked in saltwater will block very high voltage tazer hits